# How to apply a Texture to a Range in Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet in my workbook, and i'm trying to make it look better.
I Tried a google search but no luck...

i know how to apply a picture to a whole sheet (but it gets mosaique) :

`Sheets("Phase Psy").SetBackgroundPicture Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\images\magie\slayers\lina_inverse_vs__voldemort.jpg"`

also for comments, you can use either a picture or some nice preset textures :

`Range("A1").Comment.Shape.Fill.Userpicture "c:\myPic.JPG"`

or

`Range("A1").Comment.Shape.Fill.PresetTextured msoTexturePapyrus`

I would like something similar but not applyed to comments but to a range.

Is there a way to add a picture or texture, or pattern (but not the ugly ones you can find with format cell>Fill>Pattern Style) ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Test2()
ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 1").Width = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").MergeArea.Width
ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 1").Height = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").MergeArea.Height
End Sub
```

The above will fill the Cell with the picture, keeping the aspect ratio, until either the full width or height of the cell is acheived

Comment: Thanks for the answer .   Yes this is a possible way of doing it, but i wanted to avoid adding more shapes(pictures) to the worksheet, wich would be problematic with my other routines. Preferabaly i'd look for a solution using a range/sheet background property i don't know of to resolve it. Still i upped your proposition